FB Graph API to return total number of comments by day
FB recently deprecated a number of page metrics, included some we used to generate charts of user interactions divided by day.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/page/deprecated-metrics
In particular, one metric that was very useful was page_positive_feedback_by_type. It used to return a sum of actions including the counts of comments, likes, shares, over a range of time.
We tried page_post_engagements but it doesn't provide details on which types of engagement are recorded.
So far we're left without a clear way to populate a chart of page comments by a period of time. An alternative would be to get all post types, including ads, for a page, and query comments for all of them, but would result in a huge number of queries which can be both impractical or un-feasible for longer timespans or pages with lots of contents.
What are you using as replacements for these endpoints?
